# Click text-link image opens up in a box

Tags: image, popup, call, lightbox, manual

I want to write code for a pop up when you click a text link like: "Click here for my CV". Upon clicking, I'd like a pop up with my image in it, *not* to have it open in a new window.

I tried with Lightbox but it didn't work for me. The image popped up in a new window, which isn't what I want.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you will need to prevent the default action caused by clicking the link.

here is a fiddle to help

https://jsfiddle.net/bsasi/xu58hb67/1/

```
$("a").click(function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(".lightUp").toggle();
});
```